# I need to delete multiple files in multiple directories with batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, dos

This is what a Basic script would look like.

```
For directory = 643 to 776 step 1
*** Loop 1
cd directory
cd 165
*** Loop 2
    for FD1=405 to 494 step 1
    del FD1.*
    FD1 = FD +1
*** Loop 2 End
*** Loop 3  
    FD2 = 681 to 683 step 1
    del FD2.*
    FD2 = FD2 +1
*** Loop 3 End
Directory = directory plus 1
*** Loop 1
End
```

Comment: you need the `for /L` command. For example: `for /L /%%i in (343,1,776) do ...`). See `for /?` for more infos. The rest should be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "target=c:\where\files\are"
    for /l %%a in (643 1 776) do (
        for /l %%b in (405 1 494) do dir "%target%\%%a\165\%%b.*"
        for /l %%b in (681 1 683) do dir "%target%\%%a\165\%%b.*"
    )
```

`for /l %%x in (start step end) do ...` is the command you need to use to iterate over a numeric range

Probably (from your pseudocode it is not clear where the folders are located) there is no need for the `cd`. Paths can be indicated. Edit the value of the `target` variable to point to the correct folder.

This code is executing `dir` instead of `del`. If the console output is correct, change the command to remove the files.